# NIC on PCI bus only works when attached to POE supplying network

Tags: networking, power-supply, network-adapter, pci-express, pci

This is a strange one....

I have a PC with both an on-board NIC and an additional NIC in a PCI slot. The NIC in the PCI slot will only create a link when attached to a network which supplies POE.

More details:

The NIC in the PCI slot has always given me trouble. Before it stopped working, I could only get a 10Mbps link (even though it supports 10/100/1000 and was connected to a gigibit switch). I tried forcing the link speed in the driver settings to no effect. Yesterday, the NIC stopped working entirely, so I switched it out with an identical model. Same problem. The only way I can get a link is if I connect this NIC to our company LAN which supplies POE. 
My only thought is that perhaps the power supply in the PC is not providing the correct voltages to the PCI bus, but I have a GPU in one of the PCI slots, and it works just fine. Also the PC (Windows 7) can interface with the NIC with no problems.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are Jumbo Packets enabled on the PCI NIC?

Comment: So, if you put a dumb switch without POE between the company LAN and your PCI NIC, then it also stops working? When reading the title of the question, i directly thought about potential PCI Bus power supply problems too. Swapping PCI-Slots hasn't helped, i presume? Is it a server board, with several local PCI buses? If so, try a slot on another bus too.

Comment: PSU rating good enough for all items in the PC, together? One voltage bad? DC/DC and/or other circuitry related to PCI-slot half-broken first... Well, you get my point I hope. This is a job for a guy that knows the PCI-bus on that particular motherboard.

Comment: It may be helpful if you share the model number of the PCI NIC.

Comment: The issue was eventually solved by convincing IT to issue me another NIC. I still don't understand the mode of failure on the old one though